# actual and formal argument lists differ in length error in subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I am getting an error in the subclass that says:
"constructor DrawingShape in class DrawingShape cannot be applied to given types; required: java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double, double, java.awt.color
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
/**
 * Abstract class DrawingShape - a two dimensional circle or square
 *
 * @author Aidan H
 * @version 4/29/2017
 */
public abstract class DrawingShape  
{
    //center and radius of the shape
    private double radius;
    private Point2D.Double center;
    //color of the shape
    private Color color;
    /**
     * Creates a shape with the center
     * at the specified point and 
     * with the specified radius and color.
     * 
     * @param   Point2D.double   the center of the shape
     *          double           the radius of the shape
     *          Color            the color of the shape
     */
    public DrawingShape(Point2D.Double center, double radius, Color color)
    {
        this.center = center;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
    }
    //get and set methods, etc
}

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
/**
 * Write a description of class Circle here.
 * 
 * @author Aidan H
 * @version 4/29/2017
 */
public class Circle extends DrawingShape /*error underlines "cl" in "public class Circle"*/
{
    //center and radius of the circle
    private double radius;
    private Point2D.Double center;
    //color of the circle
    private Color color;
    /**
     * Creates a circle with the center
     * at the specified point and 
     * with the specified radius and color. 
     * 
     * @param   Point2D.double   the center of the shape
     *          double           the radius of the shape
     *          Color            the color of the shape
     */
    public void Circle(Point2D.Double center, double radius, Color color)
    {
        this.center = center;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
    }
    //more methods
}
```

Comment: You have to call `super` (the superclass constructor) with the arguments provided or else it will call it implicitly with no arguments. Make sure it's the first call.

Comment: @AndrewLi Thanks, but I don't know where I should put this. first thing in the class? In the constructor?

Comment: First thing in the constructor as I said.

Comment: @AndrewLi Thanks! It compiles now.